# How to add an extra shape item into a legend of fills using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, boxplot, legend-properties

I made a filled boxplot, then I put a red cross in to highlight the group means. How can I add that red cross to the legend, if the legend was constructed using `scale_fill_manual`. I tried to use `scale_shape_manual` but it didn't work.

```
library(ggplot2)

Chemical <- rep(c("NaCl", "Al2"), times = 3, each = 4)
Quality <- rep(c("Taste", "Color\nof package", "Capacity"), times = 1, each = 8)
Accepted <- seq(0, 100, by = 100/23)

DF <- data.frame(Chemical, Quality, Accepted)
means <- aggregate(Accepted ~ Chemical + Quality, DF, mean)

ggplot(DF, aes(x = Quality, y = Accepted, fill = Chemical)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "green", "red"),
                     labels = expression("Al"[2], "NaCl", "Means")) +
  geom_point(data = means, aes(x = Quality, y = Accepted),
             position = position_dodge(0.75), shape = 3, color = 2) +
  xlab("") +
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the red cross is already in the legend in your example. Are you trying to make it a stand along legend item? What would be your ideal output...?

Comment: Do you want each legend to have a "boxplot" background?  That may complicate things.  But the general default is to map fill to `"Means"` in the `aes` of `geom_point` (add `group` to keep dodging)` and then use `override.aes` in `guide_legend` to get things to look right.  You'll also probably need a named vector for `values` in `scale_fill_manual`.